# Response Entity is null despite Error-404 JSON returned by a server

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Spring REST to handle my requests.
Here is my code sample:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(apiAddress + "action?uniqueId=" + id, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        }catch (RestClientException ex) {
            System.out.println(responseEntity.toString());
            String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
        }
```

Everything is OK when I have got 200 status and JSON with returned values.
The problem is with, for example, 404 JSONs.
During the debugging I have figured out that when 404 occurs my `responseEntity` is still null so I am unable to get the error code. Moreover I am unable to get JSON reply from the server which I know that it being send.

I tried HTTP Requester which works fine with 200 responses  - giving me requested data and with 404 responses - giving me a JSON with error description.

Best Regards,
Karol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out what is going on.
I Hope that it might help someone else:

I have implemented `ResponseErrorHandler` :

```
public class VariousErrorsResponseHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    if(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND || clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) return false;
    else return true;
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    System.err.println(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode() + "\n" + clientHttpResponse.getStatusText());
}
}
```

Then set it as restTemplate's error handler:

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new VariousErrorsResponseHandler());
```

And done :)